# Я это сделал - также как и он

Tags: пунктуация

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, какой вариант правильный таки? Я думаю, что 3-й, т. к. я вообще этим предложением не хочу-с сказать, что тот человек то сделал таким же образом, как и другой; я хочу им дать понять, что "он это сначала сделал, а потом-с я это тоже сделал (и, возможно, не так же, как и он, но тоже)". Я ставлю паузу перед *также*, которое, возможно, должно писаться-таки раздельно.

1. Я сказал себе: "Я это никогда-никогда не сделаю-с!" Однако потом мне пришлось ей всё-таки по-стыдному признаться: "Я это сделал - также как и он".
2. Я сказал себе: "Я это никогда-никогда не сделаю-с!" Однако потом мне пришлось ей всё-таки по-стыдному признаться: "Я это сделал так же, как и он".
3. Я сказал себе: "Я это никогда-никогда не сделаю-с!" Однако потом мне пришлось ей всё-таки по-стыдному признаться: "Я это сделал, также как и он".

Comment: «по-стыдному» — оно из какого словаря?

Comment: По-стыдному признаться — это признаться стыдным образом (*как признаться?*), то есть делая что-то стыдное, не признаться в чём-то стыдном. Наверно, надо: *в стыдном признаться*.

Comment: Все-таки мало у нас ценят необыкновенные авторские находки,  оригинальность текста...  По-стыдному – это авторский неологизм со значением  «стыдясь».

Comment: @oleedd стыдно, это вроде возвратного, нельзя делать стыдное, зная что оно стыдное. Это вряд ли стандартный глагол. То есть довольно сложно кому-то причинить стыд. Хотя можно пристыдить, но это не совсем тоже, что причинить.

Comment: @Sharon "По-стыдному" = "стыдно". "Стыдно" ≠ "стыдясь". Неологизмы не нарушают правила речи (в данном случае функции частей речи). Вы можете как угодно интерпретировать задумку автора, но ваша интерпретация не сделает неправильную фразу правильной. Для сравнения: *по-стыдному спросил, по-стыдному сказал* (как, а не что делая при этом).

Comment: "По-стыдному признался" значит по правилам русского языка, что признался так, что от такого стало стыдно. Например, признался, стоя на коленях (это стыдно). А то, в чём признался, может быть и нестыдным.

Comment: @oleedd если уж рассуждать, то по-стыдному признался, это значит, признался так, что стало стыдно за него, а не ему, и не за то, что он признался, за форму признания что ли. Короче так не говорят, потому что это бредовое образование.

Comment: @Буратино Стыдно прежде всего ему, потому что он об этом говорит. Да, за форму признания (как признался).

Comment: @oleedd стыдно тому, кто говорит, повторяет, читает слово по-стыдному. Стыд - это личное чувство. Тебе не стыдно? а мне за тебя стыдно. А если тебе не стыдно, то стыда у тебя нет.

Comment: @Буратино Ну да. В предложении: ***мне** пришлось ей всё-таки **по-стыдному** признаться.* То есть признавался стыдным образом, по его мнению. Либо в общем — стыдно по меркам морали.

Comment: @oleedd стыд не меряется моралью, я ж говорю, стыд - это чувство. Если ты меряешь стыд моральными нормами - то это не стыд, а что-то другое. Поэтому форма по-стыдному и кривая. Признание может быть постыдное, а не по-стыдное. Не пишут так, не отделяют приставку, это целое, целостное, чувство, а не расчет на стыд, пыстыжусь мол на 25% от стыдного - нет. Так это не работает. Или стыдно или не стыдно. Или постыдно или не стыдно. Не по-стыдному - не бывает.

Comment: @Буратино Да, но можно брать в общем — что стыдно для большинства людей (не только для говорящего), тогда как бы нормы морали.

Comment: @oleedd мораль и "нормы морали" - вещи параллельные, потому что норма - это латинизм придуманный где-то в 19 веке: https://www.etymonline.com/word/norm?ref=etymonline_crossreference . Мораль - это эталон поведения. Но позже это слово получило и отрицательное значение. А чуть позже были и нормы придуманы. А норма - это линейка, поэтому это к стыду отношения не имеет. Норма - это когда сделал неправильно, ну и получил наказание по норме - и не стыдно. А стыдно - это когда не удовлетворяет ни внешняя похвала, ни формальное искупление вины.

Comment: @Pumpkin777 на мой взгляд, "также" это "тоже", а "так же" это "в той же степени". Можно сравнить "Той зимой в Москве было так же холодно, как в Сибири" и "Гамма-излучение, также как и остальные виды радиации, может вызвать ОЛБ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема **дискуссионная** (в источниках предлагаются разные мнения)

**Мой вариант решения**:  *Я сказал себе: "Я это никогда-никогда не сделаю-с!" Однако потом мне пришлось ей всё-таки по-стыдному (= стыдясь)  признаться: "Я это сделал, **также как и** он".*

1. На основании **источников** (правил Розенталя и Лопатина, а также толкового словаря Кузнецова) можно сделать вывод о существовании двух форм записи

(1) союзное соединение (1) ***ТАКЖЕ КАК И*** (2) его парный вариант ***ТАК ЖЕ КАК И***,  причем выбор определяется семантикой (***также*** или ***так... как***).

2. В заданном вопросе надо выбрать **союзное соединение** с отождествлением двух поступков  (поступил **одинаково** с ним).  Моральная оценка (поступил  **неприемлемо/по-стыдному**, так же как он) рассматривается в тексте отдельно.

**СХЕМА ДЛЯ СРАВНЕНИЯ ВАРИАНТОВ по семантике**

*Он это сделал; я, как и он, **тоже/также** это сделал.*

*Он поступил неприемлемо; я, как и он, поступил **так же неприемлемо**.*

Указательное местоимение "как" во втором предложении относится **к наречию** "неприемлемо". В первом предложении **нет местоимения** "так".

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

(1) **Так кого же слушать?** Поступать **по общей команде** (всё и всегда пишем **одинаково**) как-то не хочется. А хочется напомнить следующее: прежде всего важна **семантика.** При проверке значения союзов ***ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ*** не забываем о союзе-синониме ***И***.

**Семантическая проверка**  Он сделал (что-то), я **также/тоже** сделал, **и** я сделал (все сделали).  А **как** сделали? Он сделал плохо, я **так же** сделал (плохо), **и** я **так** сделал (плохо).

**(2) Впрочем,** **обсуждать-то и нечего!** Была команда писать одинаково, то есть раздельно! Какие еще вопросы?  **Поиски смысла** народу ни к чему, а интеллигенты пусть пишут как хотят...

**Источники по теме**

[Розенталь пункт 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)

[ПАС од ред. Лопатина § 88](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)

[Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5&all=x)

Comment: Вопрос № 298109  
Здравствуйте! В толковом словаре под ред. Кузнецова есть такой пример в статье "Также": "Он владеет французским, также как и немецким". Разве не раздельно должно писаться в этом случае "так же"? В ответах в Справке в аналогичных случаях рекомендуется писать именно раздельно. Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Орфографическая рекомендация – писать союзное сочетание *так же как (и)* раздельно.

Comment: У Розенталя и Лопатина по вашим ссылкам такого нет. Поменяйте на другие. А толковые словари орфографию не диктуют!

Comment: Тема дискуссионная (в источниках предлагаются разные мнения).  Вы можете дать свой ответ и обозначить свое понимание темы и решение данного примера. Подходящее толкование выберите в том источнике, который считаете правильным.

Comment: Нет, просто Кузнецов пошёл против всех, что нередко делаете вы. Кто неправ: один человек или все остальные? У других такого нет.

Comment: А вы не на других смотрите, а на себя.  У вас же есть свое мнение. Или должно быть...

Comment: А зачем здесь своё мнение? Есть общепринятые правила орфографии. Ну и "же" можно опустить, чего нельзя сделать, когда "также". Ну да, поступил по-стыдному. А признаётся-то уже нормально, а не по-стыдному. Потихоньку сворачиваем на правильный путь...

Comment: Общепринятые правила можно и дома почитать, а здесь обсуждаются трудные для понимания темы. Присоединяемся и обсуждаем...  Формальные подстановки/перестановки правильность не гарантируют, семантика всего важнее.

Comment: Да не говорите. Здесь полно элементарных вопросов. Не все знают, как искать и где искать. Они гарантируют, не считайте то, что вам не нравится, ненадёжным, это как обвинять невиновного человека. Здесь нет разной семантики. Представим, что она есть. Как человек на слух поймёт, какой вариант? Да никак! Поэтому это не выгодно русскому языку, и поэтому такого нет.

Comment: Про слух тоже не скажите, как и про интуицию.  Наша речь построена в основном на интуиции. Мы даже "по уму" предложение не можем построить,  такая речь кажется искусственной, надуманной.  Ну ладно, все, дайте свой ответ, его и обсудим.

Comment: При чём здесь слух? Догадываться, о чём говорят, — не самое приятное занятие. Насчёт вашей семантической проверки. Только "тоже" туда не клеится: *тоже как и он*. Или ставьте запятую и делайте присоединение: *Я это сделал, тоже, как и он.*

Comment: Кстати, автор вопроса  ПРЕДЛАГАЕТ третий вариант как возможный и паузу слышит :  "Я ставлю ПАУЗУ перед также, которое, возможно, должно писаться-таки РАЗДЕЛЬНО".  А вы голосуете за вариант без паузы.

Comment: Мне понравился факт про вопрос, а дальше и не прочитал. А за пунктуацию он не ручается. А с запятой посередине как-то не правильно получается. Почему? *Я сделал так же = Я сделал так же само*. А "как и" не стыкуется (*Я сделал так же само, как и он*), если без присоединения.

Comment: Теперь понял вашу точку зрения. Проблема в том, что "тоже" и "как и" не стыкуются по грамматике. А смысл определяется по запятой, при запятой перед смысл один — просто "как и" (своего рода устойчивое сочетание), "так же само" нет, чтобы было "так же само", надо поставить запятую посередине и убрать "и": *Я это сделал так же [само], как он.*

Answer (score 0):

> Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, какой вар. правильный таки?
>
> *Я это сделал - также как и он. Я это сделал так же, как и он. Я это сделал, также как и он.*

Правильного варианта среди перечисленных для предложенного Вами контекста –

> я вообще этим предложением не хочу-с сказать, что тот человек то
> сделал таким же образом, как и другой; я хочу им дать понять, что "он
> это сначала сделал, а потом-с я это тоже сделал (и, возможно, не так
> же, как и он, но тоже)"

– нет. Правилен такой:

*Я это сделал, **так же как** и он*.

Ср.:

*Он, **так же как** Ильюшин, учился в Военно-воздушной академии*

([ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 88](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)).

*Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, **так же как** параллельная*

([из справочника Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)).

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим все варианты:

1. Я это сделал – также как и он.
   Во-первых, перед присоединительным союзом ‟также” ставится запятая. Во-вторых у присоединительных союзов ‟также” и ‟как и” схожее значение, лучше не ставить их вместе, потому что получается что-то вроде такого: ‟Я это сделал, как и как и он”. Лучше написать так: ‟Я это сделал, как и он” или ‟Я это сделал ,также и он”.
2. Я это сделал так же, как и он.
   ‟Так же” здесь – это наречие характеристики действия. Нужно подумать над контекстом, чтобы это предложение имело бы смысл. Такое предложение тоже сомнительно, потому что представим ситуацию: кто-то говорит: ‟Сергей поступил в университет. Я сделал так же, как и он”. Тут будет избыточность, потому что мы уже после первого предложения знаем, что он сделал так же.
3. Третье такое же, как первое.

На мой взгляд, тут может быть только такой вариант: ‟Я сделал так же, как он”.

Разблокируйте, пожалуйста, мой основной аккаунт. Я обещаю больше не нарушать правила и прощу прощения у всех, кого оскорблял.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны только два последних названных Вами варианта.
**Я сделал это так же, как и он**.
Здесь имеется в виду, что автор это сделал так же, таким же образом, как и другой, второстепенный персонаж.
**Я сделал это, также как и он**.
Имеется в виду, что второстепенный персонаж сделал что-то, а автор сделал то же.
Можно предложение переделать: *Он сделал это, и я тоже*. Если автор это имел в виду, то используется третий.